# Superfish sub menus display before page is finished loading

Tags: jquery, css, drupal-7, superfish

Anyone know why this is happening? Whenever you go to a page on the site the sub menus appear briefly and then disappear when the page is done loading. I'd like to stop that from happening. Here's the url.. http://epsia.marketspacecom.com/

I'm guessing there's an issue with my CSS but I can't seem to pinpoint where the problem is :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you have to define `display:none` in `CSS` instead of giving in `JS` like this:

```
.sf-megamenu{
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: Yep.. that's it. I remembered I removed a line that was similar to that thinking it was weird to have the megamenu set to display as none. Ooops! Thanks!

Comment: How does this answer help anyone else? What is sf-megamenu? It's not part of superfish.

Comment: or you can hide this when load page: .sub-menu => .sub-menu { display: none }

Answer (score 1):

Recently i have resolve this issue on my site, I have resolved this issue by using css and jquery,
steps to solved the issue

1 add a class to the coantainer of the menu. (the property of the class should be overflow:hidden;)

2 at the footer area  remove this class after some time by using jquery.

Forexample

```
<style>.removehidden{ overflow:hidden;}</style>
<div class="removehidden" id="hidden">
    <div calss="menu">
      <!--- All inside of menu -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In the footer Area write this script

```
<script> 
     setTimeout(function(){ 
       $('#hidden').removeClass('removehidden').addClass(text); 
      },1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add following to the CSS

```
    .yourmenuwrap-class-here .sub-menu{
     display:none;
    }
```

or in a general way

```
    .sub-menu{
     display:none;
    }
```

This method switches off submenus on initial page load and activates them on hover.

Comment: I had this problem in one of my sites as pages load very slow during a maintenance on the server adding display:none to sub menu class work perfect and solve it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happens with slow rendering pages.
Several ways I found to avoid this:

1. Render it after pages finish to load, and all other init stuff
2. Render it outside the "page" i.e. left: -90000px for example
3. give the wrapper elm visibility: hidden; -> render it -> show it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try (it works for me), on superfish.css

```
ul.sf-menu ul#nav  { display:none; ...
```